# Problem with Upload file to Google Drive using google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I used these AttachFileFromJS() before and it work properly but that is in webapp deployment
,but this code has error when run inside modal on google sheet
[image: error pic]

(I'm not quite sure that make any difference?)

Code.gs

```
function UploadToDrive(){ 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Upload').setWidth(400).setHeight(300); 
    ui.showModelessDialog(html," ");
}

function AttachFileFromJS(folderId,fileObj){

    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    if(fileObj.fileName != ''){
    var data = Utilities.base64Decode(fileObj.fileData);
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, fileObj.mimeType, fileObj.fileName);
    var createFile = folder.createFile(blob);
    var picId =  createFile.getId() ;
      return picId ;
    } 
}

function Uploader(fileObj){
    var folderId =  '1VaRzewFKEUWL3DJ_uf7z6lIocFqu0P6j';
 AttachFileFromJS(folderId,fileObj)    
}
```

Upload.html (show only some part)

```
<div id="attach" name="attach">             
              <input type="file" name="file" id="fileInput" onchange="LoadFile(event)" />
              <input type="hidden" id="fileData" name="fileData" />
              <input type="hidden" id="mimeType" name="mimeType" />
              <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" />   
              
              </div><br>   
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary rounded submit px-3" onclick="UploadFile()" >Upload File</button>
                </div>
```

Javascript

```
function LoadFile(event)
  {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.result);
      var fileData = e.target.result.substr(e.target.result.indexOf(",")+1);
      var mimeTypeStart = e.target.result.indexOf("data:") + 5;
      var mimeTypeEnd = e.target.result.indexOf(";");
      var mimeType = e.target.result.substr(mimeTypeStart, mimeTypeEnd - mimeTypeStart);
      var fileName = file.name;
      document.getElementById("fileData").value = fileData;
      document.getElementById("mimeType").value = mimeType;
      document.getElementById("fileName").value = fileName;
    };    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
  }

 function UploadFile(){  
var File1 = {};
 File1.fileData     = document.getElementById("fileData").value  ;
 File1.mimeType     =  document.getElementById("mimeType").value ;
 File1.fileName     =  document.getElementById("fileName").value ; 
google.script.run.Uploader(File1) ;

 }
```

Comment: how about using built-in [Google file picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview)

Comment: Thank you , Ricardas . considering that
Now I know  problem come from
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

Class DriveApp has some problem but I dunno why?